# Please, re-open this question

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-reopen

[Why isn't Red Angel simply communicating with normal language instead of giving clues?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/207330/why-isnt-red-angel-simply-communicating-with-normal-language-instead-of-giving)

This question was closed as per our *Future Works Policy*. The recent episode of *Star Trek: Discovery* has addressed this. As this question can now be answered, please re-open it.

Comment: I don't watch that show, and I don't have much info, but it looks like it was closed as POB? The future bit seemed in addition to the main reason for closing.

Comment: @Riker POB is the close reason that encompasses​future work policy, for lack of a better, specific one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The question has now been reopened by the community.**

(For the record, [reviewers voted to leave closed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/144012) within minutes of the post entering the review queue. I don't know *Star Trek Discovery*, so can't tell if that was hasty reviewing or if the question should have stayed closed. But the reviewers are all active users and might see this meta to explain their decision.)

Comment: The post was closed per future works and was trying to be reopened only 7 days later so I, foolishly, thought it would still be FWP. Had a user commented or edited the post I would have voted to reopen. Unfortunately no one mentioned this **on the post itself**.

Comment: Just a late comment, but I've been following Discovery and indeed the latest episode answers the question, so I think voting to reopen it was a correct decision. As I was the one to originally VTC the question, I should have said this earlier, my apologies..